# Was .NET Framework listed during the 2018 survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

I noticed that .NET Core sits at 27% in the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools" section of the survey, but there's no mention of .NET Framework. Did it not register enough respondents to appear on the final list or was it not included as an option?

Come to think of it, is there a way to check the original list of options?

Comment: I believe you are correct, I do not remember seeing .NET Framework on there, only Core.

Comment: *What* **is** .NET Framework?

Comment: @Rexford That sounds like a rhetorical question. What's your point?

Comment: Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38063837/424903), I'm not surprised. Similarly, the only Java option on the list was Spring Framework.

Comment: If .NET Framework wasn't included as an option, I would imagine a lot of developers who use .NET Framework and not .NET Core would have selected the latter out of confusion (or deliberately selected it knowing it was wrong, because they wanted to represent .NET as a whole).

I think the amount of legacy WebForms and WinForms code out there alone is enough to put .NET Framework ahead of some listed frameworks, given that .NET Core doesn't support either.

Ultimately it means the 27% figure is not an accurate representation of the number of respondents who use .NET Core.

Comment: I've asked a similar question on Twitter in 2017: https://twitter.com/Kobi/status/844483365201956865 - *"I work with .Net, and marked I want to work with .Net Core. The results don't have this distinction"*

Comment: I didn't select .NET Core because I know what it is (and don't use it), but I do work with .NET Framework. People not knowing the difference that well might have checked .NET Core.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid what did you check? (out of curiosity)

Comment: @Scriptable Can't remember for sure. But I only checked stuff I actually work with. I didn't check anything as a replacement for something that was missing in the list. I do that on purpose to not mess up the statistics :)

Comment: @Rexford nice use of italics and bold - just missing a freehand circle really </sarcasm>